# popup is not displayed in in magento2 admin grid

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.2, modal-popup

I'm a beginner on Magento and I'm stuck at the pop-up level, so I did the add action button and it works fine

```
  <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Managys\Pricing\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ProductActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

but I have to change that part to open a pop -up to choose a category. I followed this tutorial but unfortunately the pop-up is not displayed:
[enter link description here](https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-button-in-magento2-admin-grid/)

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Managys\Pricing\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Sendmail">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Managys_Pricing/js/grid/columns/sendmail</item>
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Send Mail</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">13</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

is there another method?
and thank you in advance

Comment: What is the you are getting ?

Comment: Hi  lisa 
Please check the following answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/292029/59216

Dont forget to upvote! :)