# Open Modal in ActionsColumn

Tags: magento2, product, uicomponent

I have a grid in admin product form. In actionColumns there is a action to edit the row of grid. I would like to open modal when click in the edit.

All examples redirect to other page.

Thanks

Comment: I am also looking for same feature, Do you get any solution? Thanks,
Vishves Shah

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134462)

Comment: Hi  Ismael 
Please check the following answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/292029/59216

Don't forget to upvote! :)