# popup in admin grid magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent, popup

I am using admin grid where I have product grid. In product grid I have action as of now this is link redirecting to new page. But I want when I click on link it open as popup. Like when we adding attribute while creating product [image]

Any ideas how we can do this?

Comment: Please follow below link may it can help you
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-modal.html

Comment: Hi  Daniel 
Please check the following answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/292029/59216

Dont forget to upvote! :)