# How to create a Grid View Slider. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, view

I'm trying to create *View* Slider in my custom grid like
[image]

for that I've followed [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279944/magento-2-how-to-add-grid-phtml-file-on-slide-out-panel-popup-modal-in-custo/301915#301915) and [This](https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/add-view-button-in-admin-grid-to-open-a-view-page-in-slide-window-in-magento-2/) but in the both cases when I click on my custom link or button it gives me an error in *console*
[image]

Now I dont know why this is happening in both of the cases.. any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please put below div where you want to display data.

```
<div id="popupId"></div>
```

and please use below function where you want to open popup Model data.

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ], function ($,example,modal) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: 'primary action submit btn btn-default',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };
    
            jQuery('.order-status-review').on('click', function() {
                var orderId = jQuery(this).data("orderid");
                var commentId = jQuery(this).data("commentid");
                var statusId = jQuery(this).data("statusid");
    
                $.ajax({
                      method: "POST",
                      showLoader: true,
                      url: "<?php  echo $block->getUrl('contrller path'); ?>",
                      data: { orderid: orderId,commentid:commentId,statusid:statusId}
                    })
                  .done(function( data ) {
                      if(data.orderstatusHtml != ""){
                        $("#popupId").html(data.orderstatusHtml).modal(options).modal('openModal'); 
                      }
                  });
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
```

You can modifed this function as per your requirement.

also, you have to created one controller which fetch data according your need and put it in your popup data div.

i hope this solve your problem

Thanks,